# My drawer is throwing " Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget." using a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a ListView inside my drawer so when the screen orientation change i don't get an overflow error.
But as soon i add my ListView to the drawer it do not render anymore and i'm getting the errors :

```
I/flutter (13071): Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
I/flutter (13071): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#91f4f relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
```

And i couldn't figure out hwy my code do not work. Doew someone has an idea why ?

Thank you !

This is my code :

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        child: Flex(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, bottom: 20),
                child: Text(
                  "test",
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```